# Default xsession for new users

Tags: xorg, users, gdm, session, gnome-session

How do I change the default xsession for **new** users which will be added to the system in the future?

I know I can change the last/default session for an **existing** user by editing the setting `XSession=` in `/var/lib/AccountsService/users/username`

But obviously this file is not created yet for new users. It also seems to be  not `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf`

```
...
[daemon]
DefaultSession=mysession
....
```

I was not able to locate the default value in 18.04/gdm3